# How to know when GridView is completely drawn and ready?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a long GridView with custom adapter, How do I know when GridView is completely displayed and ready?

Here's my problem in code:

```
dashboard = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.dashboard);
dashboard.setAdapter(new ListItemsAdapter(this, allIcons));
AlertSomeItemsOfTheListView();
```

in the sequence the method "AlertSomeItemsOfTheListView" is executed before the GridView is completely drawn.

Comment: oh ! BTW how long the listview is?

Comment: You don't. The ListView will ask the adapter only for those items that are currently showing.

Comment: The problem is that I want to alter the content of the ListView using external method, but when I write them in 2 following lines the 2nd line is executed before the listView is complete drawn.

Comment: @KalpeshLakhani It's actually a gridview with 4 rows and 4 columns, But the code in getView in the adapter consumes sometime cause it puts external reference to TextView and ImageView in the ListItem (To be used by the external Method for altering its content later).

Comment: ok ! buddy understood your problem. and yes critical it is. By the way try lazy loading for this case if you comfort with.

Comment: I found a work around "The Polling Way" (the last item that I would want to alter toggles a public boolean when it's called in getView), and my other method sleeps 100 ms and checks for this boolean, once it the bolean is toggled, it starts changing the content of the layout.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could get [`ViewTreeObserver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html) instance for your `GridView` and use it to listen for events such as `onLayout`. You can get `ViewTreeObserver` for your `View` using [`View.getViewTreeObserver()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getViewTreeObserver()). I am not sure if `onLayout` event will be enough for you as it does not exactly mean that a `View` is fully drawn but you can give it a try.

Here there is a code sample which you could use to listen for `onLayout` event (you could use such code e.g. in `onCreate` method of your `Activity`):

```
dashboard.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
    new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            AlertSomeItemsOfTheListView();

            // unregister listener (this is important)
            dashboard.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        }
    });
```

**Note:** It is important to unregister listener after it is invoked. If you don't do that it will be invoked on every `onLayout`event which is not what we want here (we want it to execute only once).

Comment: For V13 + "removeGlobalOnLayoutListener" is deprecated.  Use removeOnGlobalLayoutListener instead.

Answer (score 0):

When a GridView/ListView has an adapter, it calls getView when it displays items that are to be in view. If you REALLY needed to call a method after all Views are shown, you could do something like....

```
while(!dashboard.getAdapter().areAllItemsEnabled()){
   //wait
}

AlertSomeItemsOfTheListView();
```

I'm not positive that this will work, but looking at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#getAdapter() and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html make it seem like it will.

Comment: I found a work around similar to your answer "The Polling Way" (the last item that I would want to alter toggles a public boolean when it's called in getView), and my other method sleeps 100 ms and checks for this boolean, once it the bolean is toggled, it starts changing the content of the layout