# Recyclerview, I can't get item view with getChildAt(position). Null object reference

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, get-childitem

I am using a recyclerView inside my navigation drawer and I am using this library [Twoway-view](https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view) to get click and selection support.

It works perfectly and I can change the color of the text and the icons without problems inside OnClick method for each position:

```
itemClickSupport.setOnItemClickListener(new ItemClickSupport.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(RecyclerView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
            MainActivity.this.getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.colorAccent, typedValue, true);
            final int color = typedValue.data;

            //TODO Icon and text colors

            for (int i = 0; i < drawerTitles.length; i++){
                if (i == position){
                    ImageView imageViewDrawerIcon = (ImageView) recyclerViewDrawer.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.imageViewDrawerIcon);
                    TextView textViewDrawerTitle = (TextView) recyclerViewDrawer.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.textViewDrawerItemTitle);
                    imageViewDrawerIcon.setColorFilter(color);
                    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 15){
                        imageViewDrawerIcon.setImageAlpha(255);
                    }else{
                        imageViewDrawerIcon.setAlpha(255);
                    }
                    textViewDrawerTitle.setTextColor(color);
                    RelativeLayout relativeLayoutDrawerItem = (RelativeLayout) recyclerViewDrawer.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.relativeLayoutDrawerItem);
                    relativeLayoutDrawerItem.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                }else{
                    ImageView imageViewDrawerIcon = (ImageView) recyclerViewDrawer.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.imageViewDrawerIcon);
                    TextView textViewDrawerTitle = (TextView) recyclerViewDrawer.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.textViewDrawerItemTitle);
                    imageViewDrawerIcon.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.md_text));
                    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 15){
                        imageViewDrawerIcon.setImageAlpha(138);
                    }else{
                        imageViewDrawerIcon.setAlpha(138);
                    }
                    textViewDrawerTitle.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.md_text));
                    RelativeLayout relativeLayoutDrawerItem = (RelativeLayout) recyclerViewDrawer.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.relativeLayoutDrawerItem);
                    relativeLayoutDrawerItem.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
                }
            }

            //TODO Fragments (closedrawers before setfragment)
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // Do something after some time

                }
            }, 250);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        }
    });
```

The problem is that I want to access to the first item like in that method, but before it (to set the first item selected, with different color, etc).

But I get a crash (null reference) when I try to get the first item outside OnClick method:

```
ImageView imageViewDrawerIcon = (ImageView) recyclerViewDrawer.getChildAt(0).findViewById(R.id.imageViewDrawerIcon);
```

All code:

```
// Setup RecyclerView inside drawer
    recyclerViewDrawer = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewDrawer);
    recyclerViewDrawer.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerViewDrawer.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));

    ArrayList<DrawerItem> drawerItems = new ArrayList<>();
    final String[] drawerTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.drawer);
    final TypedArray drawerIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.drawerIcons);
    for (int i = 0; i < drawerTitles.length; i++) {
        drawerItems.add(new DrawerItem(drawerTitles[i], drawerIcons.getDrawable(i)));
    }
    drawerIcons.recycle();
    adapterDrawer = new DrawerAdapter(drawerItems);
    recyclerViewDrawer.setAdapter(adapterDrawer);

    // Here is the problem
    ImageView imageViewDrawerIcon2 = (ImageView) recyclerViewDrawer.getChildAt(0).findViewById(R.id.imageViewDrawerIcon);

    // RecyclerView item listener.
    ItemClickSupport itemClickSupport = ItemClickSupport.addTo(recyclerViewDrawer);
    itemClickSupport.setOnItemClickListener(new ItemClickSupport.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(RecyclerView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
            MainActivity.this.getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.colorAccent, typedValue, true);
            final int color = typedValue.data;

            //TODO Icon and text colors

            for (int i = 0; i < drawerTitles.length; i++){
                if (i == position){
                    ImageView imageViewDrawerIcon = (ImageView) recyclerViewDrawer.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.imageViewDrawerIcon);
                    TextView textViewDrawerTitle = (TextView) recyclerViewDrawer.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.textViewDrawerItemTitle);
                    imageViewDrawerIcon.setColorFilter(color);
                    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 15){
                        imageViewDrawerIcon.setImageAlpha(255);
                    }else{
                        imageViewDrawerIcon.setAlpha(255);
                    }
                    textViewDrawerTitle.setTextColor(color);
                    RelativeLayout relativeLayoutDrawerItem = (RelativeLayout) recyclerViewDrawer.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.relativeLayoutDrawerItem);
                    relativeLayoutDrawerItem.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                }else{
                    ImageView imageViewDrawerIcon = (ImageView) recyclerViewDrawer.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.imageViewDrawerIcon);
                    TextView textViewDrawerTitle = (TextView) recyclerViewDrawer.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.textViewDrawerItemTitle);
                    imageViewDrawerIcon.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.md_text));
                    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 15){
                        imageViewDrawerIcon.setImageAlpha(138);
                    }else{
                        imageViewDrawerIcon.setAlpha(138);
                    }
                    textViewDrawerTitle.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.md_text));
                    RelativeLayout relativeLayoutDrawerItem = (RelativeLayout) recyclerViewDrawer.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.relativeLayoutDrawerItem);
                    relativeLayoutDrawerItem.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
                }
            }

            //TODO Fragments (closedrawers before setfragment)
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // Do something after some time

                }
            }, 250);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RecyclerView - Get view at particular position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33784369/recyclerview-get-view-at-particular-position)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved finally with this ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14119464/3262021)):

```
recyclerViewDrawer.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            ImageView imageViewDrawerIcon = (ImageView) recyclerViewDrawer.getChildAt(0).findViewById(R.id.imageViewDrawerIcon);
            TextView textViewDrawerTitle = (TextView) recyclerViewDrawer.getChildAt(0).findViewById(R.id.textViewDrawerItemTitle);
            imageViewDrawerIcon.setColorFilter(color);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 15) {
                imageViewDrawerIcon.setImageAlpha(255);
            } else {
                imageViewDrawerIcon.setAlpha(255);
            }
            textViewDrawerTitle.setTextColor(color);
            RelativeLayout relativeLayoutDrawerItem = (RelativeLayout) recyclerViewDrawer.getChildAt(0).findViewById(R.id.relativeLayoutDrawerItem);
            relativeLayoutDrawerItem.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            // unregister listener (this is important)
            recyclerViewDrawer.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        }
    });
```

By the way, if someone have a better solution I would like to know it.

Comment: We're still getting some instances of `getChildViiew(0)` being null with this approach. I personally can't reproduce it. Using `setAdapter` triggers the child view inflation so ideally there would be a callback that is called when the child view is inflated and added to the RecyclerView

Answer (score 20):

In my case it,is work like a charm

```
View viewItem = recycleView.getLayoutManager().findViewByPosition(position);
    View icon = viewItem.findViewById(R.id.view);
```

Comment: Gives warning "Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView"

Comment: it returns `null`

Comment: Seems it works only if item is visible right now, useless. Even if I call `layoutManager.scrollToPosition(position)` before calling `findViewByPosition(position)` it still doesn't work

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me.

```
recyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    View viewItem = recycleView.getLayoutManager().findViewByPosition(position);
    View icon = viewItem.findViewById(R.id.view);
  }
});
```

Comment: Nice, this worked perfectly for getting the displayed children and viewholders using `getChildAt()` and `getChildViewHolder()`

Comment: Of note is that you can't manipulate many UI elements with this, since you're working from a different thread. You'll have to set up inter-thread communication.

Answer (score 5):

I would use [findViewHolderForAdapterPosition()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(int)) or [findViewByPosition(](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager.html#findViewByPosition(int))) instead to find the root view at that index. The way you ensure the data is loaded is up to you, however.

Answer (score 1):

`findViewByPosition` is a method of `LayoutManager`, which works with all LayoutManagers.

So you can use `recycleView.getLayoutManager()` and `findViewByPosition(pos)`.

Also `recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(pos)` works too.

For more information, look at this [RecyclerView - Get view at particular position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33784369/recyclerview-get-view-at-particular-position)

Answer (score 0):

You can get ItemView from recyclerView's holder using below code:

```
val holder = yourRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position)
if (holder != null) {
  val rootView = holder.itemView
  //do your code here
}
```