# RecyclerView Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

This might look like a repeated question but it's not!

I get this rare crash on my RecyclerView

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 
Inconsistency detected. 
Invalid item position 1(offset:1).state:4 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5014).
```

I am pretty sure that I am not missing any notification to my adapter after data change!.

Apart from the crash, one thing I can't get my head around is that I am using android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView and the crash is at line 5014  in that java file

**CODE FROM RecyclerView.java where my crash was happening**

```
 if (offsetPosition < 0 || offsetPosition >= mAdapter.getItemCount()) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Inconsistency detected. Invalid item "
                    + "position " + position + "(offset:" + offsetPosition + ")."
                    + "state:" + mState.getItemCount());
        }
```

so for this to crash either

```
offsetPosition < 0
```

or

```
offsetPosition >= mAdapter.getItemCount()
```

from the crash log clearly, my offsetPosition is 1 so

```
offsetPosition >= mAdapter.getItemCount()
```

has to be true!! but in my adapter, I implemented getItemCount like this

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size() + 3;
}
```

so at least getItemCount should return 3 so 2nd statement also can't be true.

full crash log

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position 1(offset:1).state:4
                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5014)
                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4970)
                                     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2029)
                                     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1414)
                                     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1377)
                                     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:578)
                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3315)
                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3124)
                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3568)
                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16651)
                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16651)
                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16651)
                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16651)
                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
                                     at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:131)
                                     at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
                                     at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1364)
                                     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:846)
                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16651)
                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
                                     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1197)
                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16651)
                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16651)
                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16651)
                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16651)
                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16651)
                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                                     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2678)
                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16651)
                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2183)
                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1943)
```

what am I missing here? please help!!
thanks!.

Comment: did you change adapter data in back thread?

Comment: Where are u initialising offsetPosition

Comment: @shayanpourvatan no, this adapter has its own shallow copy of array list.

Comment: @vipinagrahari that code snippet about offset is in framework's recyclerView class line 5014 ( my crash point from logs), I don't know anything about that offsetPosition variable or its purpose, but from logs clearly shows that my offestPosition value is '1'(Invalid item position 1(offset:1).state:4 ). so offsetPosition < 0 is false and offsetPosition >= mAdapter.getItemCount() is also false!!

Comment: did you get ViewHolder from layoutManager or recyclerView or other way in code, i mean for smarting update and other stuff. did this crash happened all time ?

Comment: @shayanpourvatan sorry I didn't get your question, what is smarting update? I use LinearLayoutManager for recyclerView, also this crash is very   very rare,

Comment: I mean something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33784369/recyclerview-get-view-at-particular-position

Comment: Check to make sure the adapter in your recycler view is set to what you think it is (I'm guessing it either isn't set or is set to an instance that has an itemcount of 0).

Comment: @shayanpourvatan I am not using any, I don't have  requirement like that

Comment: @CJames the only place I call setAdapter is in onCreate of my activity and I never called it again ( no setAdapter(null) or anything like that!), and my list is initiated  (list = new ArrayList<>();) in adapter's constructor and never set to null, only operations like clear() and addAll() are called and notified immediately

Comment: Very mysterious. You say the crash is rare. Normally I would be looking for  multi-threading issues when I see inconsistent (or rare) crashes. Does your app support screen rotation (that can also be a cause of mysterious crashes)

Comment: @CJames sorry for late reply, yes it was my mistake crash was due to a different adapter in different screen I blindly assumed that it was the adapter in the current screen. I apologize for this question to everyone . by the way how do I know which recyclerView is this from the crash log? is there anyway to find out its view id or something ?

Comment: @kr15hna you're a lifesaver! I've been trying to fix this for days and didn't even think it could have been a separate adapter causing the issue. Thanks!