# LinearLayoutManager.findViewByPosition() is returning null

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, linearlayoutmanager

My Activity is showing a `RecyclerView` with a `LinearLayoutManager`. I want to get the first item (`View`) in the list. According [this post's accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33784369/recyclerview-get-view-at-particular-position) , I can do it calling `LinearLayoutManager.findViewByPosition()` method, but I'm getting `null` instead. Why?

```
RecyclerView list = findViewById(R.id.list);
LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
list.setLayoutManager(llm);
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter();
list.setAdapter(adapter);
View firstViewItem = llm.findViewByPosition(0); // <-- null
```

`adapter` contains items, it's not empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the population of the `RecyclerView` by the `Adapter` is asynchronous.
You may launch an event when the adapter finish to populate the RecyclerView to be sure that `findViewByPosition` returns something to you.

Detect when RecyclerView have finished to populate all visible items is a bit difficult, because we should calculate each item size (width and height) and define how many items can enter in current device display.

But if what you need is only to access first populated item then you can fire your event in your Adapter's `onBindViewHolder` method, obviously inserting the needed controls to avoid to fire events for every added item.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can listen to that event?

Comment: You can use something like Otto Event Bus. It is a good event lib to use. You could find some examples on the web. I suggest you to use event approach wherever is possible, it helps to improve performance and it helps to write clear code

Comment: But, I mean, how do I know when RecyclerView has been populated?

Answer (score 5):

A useful function is doOnPreDraw - you should call it on the RecyclerView and put your code there.

```
 rv.doOnPreDraw {
     // now it will work... 
     val view = llm.findViewByPosition(0)
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

try this.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
         View firstViewItem = llm.findViewByPosition(0);
     }
 }, 500);
```

Comment: it will work because recycler view takes some time to bind item on it. otherwise you can get it on any button click. because exact after setAdapter is never return a view.

Comment: This works well to debug the code but not something to place on production ! Thanks !

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea. In fact, I think all the timeout "tricks" on waiting for RecyclerViews to load are bad ideas. You cannot guarantee whether the RecyclerView can finish loading after certain amount of time, especially when there's a lot of item in it. `onGlobalLayout` should be a better approach

Answer (score 1):

Use `OnGlobalLayoutListener` to wait for `RecyclerView` to finish loading its items:

```
myRecyclerView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        // do you stuff here...
    }
});
```