# Android MVVM and Shared Element Transitions with RecycleView

Tags: android, android-fragments, mvvm, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I'm trying to wrap my head around implementation of shared view transitions between fragments

The challenge is coming from the MVVP restricitons:

- Adapter of `RecycleView` has knowledge of selected element and view attached via callback from `View`
- Adapter is passing information about click to `ViewModel` **stripping out** all information about view, as it can't hold it. That's because of rule - no android imports in `ViewModel` except of `*arch`
- `ViewModel` sends event to `Fragment` to open another `Fragment`
- At this point `Fragment` doesn't know what view to use to start transition in `.addSharedElement(..)`

How to address this issue?

I was thinking about saving reference to clicked `View` inside `Fragment` instance but it looks like a cheating

Any ideas and suggestions are very welcome

Comment: How about passing a position from `ViewModel` to `Fragment`. Based on that position you can get a `view` from `LayoutManager`

Comment: @Demigod it could be a solution but there is a corner case when view can be already recycled or represent another entity. Do you have examples how to access view via `LayoutManager` based on the index of element in adapter?

Comment: sure it can be done as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/33798938/3569545