# How to get specific position view in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, data-binding, android-adapter, android-databinding

I have a `recyclerView. One of` recyclerView items has an `onClick` method. In this method, I `setVisibility` for one Item to Visible(default is gone), also get the position and add it to an `arrayList`.

**onClick :**

```
public void onClickImageView(ImageView imageView, int position) {
    imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    positionArrayList.add(position);
}
```

Before i go to another activity, I want to the `ImageView` visibility be reset to default (gone) so I use an interface to send positionArrayList to the `recyclerView` activity to get views by position and reset `ImageView`s to default.

**Interface :**

```
public interface RecyclerViewMainActivityImp {
    void resetImageViewToDefault(ArrayList<Integer> positionArrayList);
}
```

**Where I use interface method in adapter :**

```
public void OnClickNextActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(context, ClassActivity.class);
    context.startActivity(intent);
    recyclerViewInterface.resetImageViewToDefault(positionArrayList);
}
```

**Activity :**

```
@Override
public void resetImageViewToDefault(ArrayList<Integer> positionArrayList) {
    for (int position = 0; position < positionArrayList.size(); position++) {
        View row = binding.recyclerView.getLayoutManager().findViewByPosition(positionArrayList.get(position));
        ImageView imageView = row.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);    
    }
}
```

When i scroll the `recyclerView`, and if some items are not in view anymore their views going to null so some positions in positionArrayList no longer have their view.

**My problem** is some views are null after scrolling and I don't know how to get access to them.

I searched on google and found some solutions but I could not solve my problem

**Note :** I have used `data binding`

Comment: adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: @Pouria Hemati doesn't work

Comment: The only way I can think of  is to use a [Binding Adapters](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters) to control the Visibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's workaround you can try for this,

create a function in your activity

```
function void updateRecyclerView(position){
   yourArrayListForVisibility.set(position,'hide');
   mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}


@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

call this function in your adapter before intent and in your adapter check for this arraylist value to hide or show content, always set default value to 'yourArrayListForVisibility' for every position

Comment: I don't use arrayList to show or hide items

Comment: recyclerview kind of create views again when they are back to visible, so if you want to maintain state of any views create a arraylist that contain some value to define that image should visible or hidden and update original value when you want to change the state

Answer (score 0):

Any Activity that restarts has its `onResume()` method executed first.
So, call [`notifyDataSetChanged()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyDataSetChanged()) of `RcyclerView` from `onResume()`

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

Comment: I did it but it doesn't work and still not reset